# Crystal Reports for VS 2013 deploy failed to open the connection in IIS 7.5

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2013.  The reports work fine on my local computer and in Visual Studio on the production server.
When I deploy them in IIS 7.5 I am getting the following error:

> Failed to open the connection.  ReportName
>   3400_4400_{A861BA52-167D-4EAF-AAAF-32B2FB34FFAA}.rpt
>
> Operating System: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise;
>   System Type: 64-bit Operating System;
>   Database: MySQL;

I copied the aspnet_clients folder in the wwwroot folder and in the application folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: check if IIS Application Pools/ my web app/ Advanced Settings the 32 bit Applications is enabled, same for 64 bit

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried enabling 32 bit Application in the Application Pool & restarted IIS but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 things which may cause this issue,

1. Are you installed the Crystal report runtime? if no, then here is
   [link1](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824), [link2](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+v.+9.1+to+SAP+Crystal+Reports+2013,+Runtime+Distribution+and+Supported+Operating+Systems). You can choose 64 bit option.
2. If you installed CR-runtime, then crystal report does not have connect to sqlserver. So for this, if you able to check your local crystal report with prod sqlconnection, check that and still you have issue, means you are not give sql server credential to crystal report at run-time. Check this link.

[Crystal Report throws 'Failed to open the connection.' only on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914605/crystal-report-throws-failed-to-open-the-connection-only-on-postback)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/667950/crystal-reports-connection-to-sql-server-database

http://aspalliance.com/532_Understanding_the_Login_Failed_Error_in_Crystal_Reports.3

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I installed Crystal Report runtime.  The odd thing is the report connects fine to MySQL from Visual Studio on that server....  I am not getting any additional error message / description, no error logs... only that "failed to open the connection" message...

Answer (score 0):

I have some updates!!! I can't believe this was the issue....so frustrating!!!...
On my production server I only created a User DNS...which worked fine with Visual Studio...but not with IIS.  After I created a System DNS the report worked fine in IIS as well...