# Crystal report: failed to open connection

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, odbc

My database is a remote Mysql database, I'm able to access the crystal reports of my application through various PC's but there is a problem with one PC, Even though I installed mysql connector and created a connection with my database which was successful using ODBC. But while I load the report it displays a message "Failed to open connection"
[image]

I have used the following code for the manual connection:

```
cI.ServerName = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=x.x.x.x;Port=3306;Option=3;";
            cI.DatabaseName = "dbName";
            cI.UserID = "username";
            cI.Password = "pass";

            foreach (IConnectionInfo info in report.DataSourceConnections)
            {
                info.SetConnection(cI.ServerName, cI.DatabaseName, cI.UserID, cI.Password);
            }

            foreach (ReportDocument sub in report.Subreports)
            {
                foreach (IConnectionInfo info in sub.DataSourceConnections)
                {
                    info.SetConnection(cI.ServerName, cI.DatabaseName, cI.UserID, cI.Password);
                }
            }
```

I get this exception:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800002F4): Failed to open the connection.
Failed to open the connection.
temp_32398d30-5e82-45f2-a356-0abdad3ba4c5 5168_1588_{1AF659C8-D14D-479F-B268-51AD72B9420A}.rpt
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.SetTableLocation(ISCRTable CurTable, ISCRTable NewTable)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.set_Location(String value)
   at School.UserInterface.StudentApp.PrintStudentInformation.connect(ReportDocument report)
   at School.UserInterface.StudentApp.PrintStudentInformation.PrintStudentInformation_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Have you checked, any dummy report opening on this PC? Or it is an issue with this Report only?

Comment: Can you debug and see the details of the exception

Comment: @ItiTyagi all the reports from this database are causing this problem

Comment: @aMazing the problem is it's my clients PC, I can't run visual studio over there for debugging purposes, what should I do?

Comment: @aMazing I managed to get the exception message please have a look at my edited question

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/986065/System-Runtime-InteropServices
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914605/crystal-report-throws-failed-to-open-the-connection-only-on-postback
https://scn.sap.com/thread/1484439
http://forums.asp.net/t/997655.aspx?Crystal+Failed+to+open+Connection

Comment: @aMazing It's weird but after I installed ODBC 32 bit on the client pc it worked, even though it already had ODBC 64 bit installed

Comment: Seems like the problem has been solved.

Comment: thats good. you can post the solution that worked as an Answer below as per the guidelines and score yourself some brownie points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of struggle, I managed to solve the problem turns out that I had to install MySQL ODBC 32Bit version on the PC which was having this problem, even though that PC already had MySQL ODBC installed but it was 64 bit version. 
So, If anyone is facing a similar problem then I suggest that you should install both versions of MySQL ODBC if your PC is 64 bit PC.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, finally after 2 days of research i was able to resolve the issue by adding the below code

```
reportDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(userId, password, serverName, database, true);
reportDoc.VerifyDatabase();
reportDoc.Refresh();
```